# What is wrong with if else statement in my Python code

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to do follow python code.. but every time I try, There is an error. they said Syntax error..(elif).How i figure this out.Or is there any wrong with my write function...?

```
file = open("text.txt","a")
n=0
while n<=5:
 y = str(input("name: "))
 x = int(input("marks: "))
 result = "Pass"
 if x<35:
    result = "Fail"
    print(y,result)
 file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif 35<=x<=54:
    result = "S"
    print(y,result)
 file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif 55<=x<=64:
    result = "C"
    print(y,result)
 file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif 65<=x<=74:
    result = "B"
    print(y,result)
 file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif (75<=x<=100):
    result = "A"
    print(y,result)
 file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 else:
    print ("Invalid Enter")
 n = n+1
file.close
```

Comment: Your `elif` has to be indented at the same level as your `if` block.

Comment: Spelling mistake. Ident your `file.writes` to the lvl of the print above it.

Comment: @JacobIRR they are. the `file.write` lines are out of order.

Comment: It is recommended to use 4 spaces as ident. you use 1 and 4 - use 4 consistently

Comment: Flagged for removal for posting about a typographic error.

Answer (score 1):

You have some indentation errors. An if-else statement should look like:

```
if x == 1:
    print(1)
    print(2)
elif x == 2:
    print(3)
    print(4)
```

Notice how all of the lines between `if` and `elif` are indented!

Also, the last line of your code is `file.close`. That should be `file.close()`, it is a method. See the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

They python documentation for the if/else statements can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your write statement is out of indent.

```
file = open("text.txt","a")
n=0
while n<=5:
 y = str(input("name: "))
 x = int(input("marks: "))
 result = "Pass"
 if x<35:
    result = "Fail"
    print(y,result)
    file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif 35<=x<=54:
    result = "S"
    print(y,result)
    file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif 55<=x<=64:
    result = "C"
    print(y,result)
    file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif 65<=x<=74:
    result = "B"
    print(y,result)
    file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 elif (75<=x<=100):
    result = "A"
    print(y,result)
    file.write('"{}#{}"/n', format(y,result))
 else:
    print ("Invalid Enter")
 n = n+1
file.close
```